# cudnn RNN implementation with status execution_failed

Tags: cudnn

I write a simple application in order to test cudnn rnn apis and check whether my understanding is correct or not;

the code is like this,

```
int layernum = 1;
int batchnum = 32;
int hiddenSize = 64;
float* h_weight, *h_hx_, *h_cx_, *h_hy_, *h_cy_;
float* h_input, *d_input;
float* h_output, *d_output;
cudnnHandle_t cu_dnnHandle;
cudnnDropoutDescriptor_t cu_dropoutDesc = nullptr;
cudnnRNNDescriptor_t cu_rnnDesc;
cudnnTensorDescriptor_t     hx_desc_;
cudnnTensorDescriptor_t     cx_desc_;
cudnnTensorDescriptor_t     hy_desc_;
cudnnTensorDescriptor_t     cy_desc_;

checkCUDNN(cudnnCreate(&cu_dnnHandle));
checkCUDNN(cudnnCreateRNNDescriptor(&cu_rnnDesc));
checkCUDNN(cudnnCreateDropoutDescriptor(&cu_dropoutDesc));
float drop_rate = 0.0f;
unsigned long long seed = 1337ull;
checkCUDNN(cudnnSetDropoutDescriptor(cu_dropoutDesc, cu_dnnHandle, drop_rate, NULL, 0, seed));
checkCUDNN(cudnnSetRNNDescriptor_v5(cu_rnnDesc,
    hiddenSize, //hiddenSize
    layernum,  //numLayers
    cu_dropoutDesc,
    //CUDNN_SKIP_INPUT,
    CUDNN_LINEAR_INPUT,
    CUDNN_UNIDIRECTIONAL,
    CUDNN_LSTM,
    CUDNN_DATA_FLOAT
    ));

checkCUDNN(cudnnCreateTensorDescriptor(&hx_desc_));
checkCUDNN(cudnnCreateTensorDescriptor(&cx_desc_));
checkCUDNN(cudnnCreateTensorDescriptor(&hy_desc_));
checkCUDNN(cudnnCreateTensorDescriptor(&cy_desc_));

std::vector<cudnnTensorDescriptor_t> tensorDescs;
std::vector<cudnnTensorDescriptor_t> resultDescs;

int seq_len = 8;

tensorDescs.resize(seq_len);
resultDescs.resize(seq_len);
for (auto i = 0; i < seq_len; i++)
{
    int dims[3] = {batchnum, 64, 1}; //batch = 32
    int strides[3] = {64, 1, 1};
    cudnnCreateTensorDescriptor(&tensorDescs[i]);
    cudnnSetTensorNdDescriptor(tensorDescs[i],
        CUDNN_DATA_FLOAT,
        3,
        dims,
        strides
        );

    cudnnCreateTensorDescriptor(&resultDescs[i]);
    cudnnSetTensorNdDescriptor(resultDescs[i],
        CUDNN_DATA_FLOAT,
        3,
        dims,
        strides
    );
}

size_t workspace_size = 0;
checkCUDNN(cudnnGetRNNWorkspaceSize(cu_dnnHandle,
    cu_rnnDesc,
    seq_len,
    tensorDescs.data(),
    &workspace_size));
std::cout << workspace_size << std::endl;
void* work_space_;
void* param_space_;
cudaMalloc(&work_space_, workspace_size);
cudnnFilterDescriptor_t     w_desc_;
size_t param_size;
checkCUDNN(cudnnGetRNNParamsSize(cu_dnnHandle, cu_rnnDesc, tensorDescs[0],
    &param_size, CUDNN_DATA_FLOAT));

cudaMalloc(&param_space_, param_size);
int w_dim[3] = { (int)(param_size / sizeof(float)), 1, 1 };
checkCUDNN(cudnnCreateFilterDescriptor(&w_desc_));
checkCUDNN(cudnnSetFilterNdDescriptor(w_desc_, CUDNN_DATA_FLOAT, CUDNN_TENSOR_NCHW, 3, w_dim));
h_weight = new float[param_size/sizeof(float)];
srand(time(NULL));

for (int i = 0; i < param_size / sizeof(float); i++)
{
    h_weight[i] = (float)rand() / RAND_MAX;
}

cudaMemcpy(param_space_, h_weight, param_size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

h_input = new float[batchnum * 64];
for (int i = 0; i < batchnum * 64; i++)
{
    h_input[i] = (float)rand() / RAND_MAX;
}
cudaMalloc(&d_input, batchnum * 64 * sizeof(float));

cudaMemcpy(d_input, h_input, batchnum * 64 * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

cudaMalloc(&d_output, batchnum * 64 * sizeof(float));

int h_dim[3] = { layernum , batchnum , hiddenSize };
int stride[3] = { h_dim[1] * h_dim[2], h_dim[2], 1 };
checkCUDNN(cudnnSetTensorNdDescriptor(hx_desc_, CUDNN_DATA_FLOAT, 3, h_dim, stride));
checkCUDNN(cudnnSetTensorNdDescriptor(cx_desc_, CUDNN_DATA_FLOAT, 3, h_dim, stride));
checkCUDNN(cudnnSetTensorNdDescriptor(hy_desc_, CUDNN_DATA_FLOAT, 3, h_dim, stride));
checkCUDNN(cudnnSetTensorNdDescriptor(cy_desc_, CUDNN_DATA_FLOAT, 3, h_dim, stride));

int bunch_hidden_size = h_dim[0] * h_dim[1] * h_dim[2];
h_hx_ = new float[bunch_hidden_size];
h_cx_ = new float[bunch_hidden_size];
h_hy_ = new float[bunch_hidden_size];
h_cy_ = new float[bunch_hidden_size];

float *d_hx_, *d_cx_, *d_hy_, *d_cy_;
cudaMalloc(&d_hx_, bunch_hidden_size * sizeof(float));
cudaMalloc(&d_cx_, bunch_hidden_size * sizeof(float));
cudaMalloc(&d_hy_, bunch_hidden_size * sizeof(float));
cudaMalloc(&d_cy_, bunch_hidden_size * sizeof(float));

for (int i = 0; i < bunch_hidden_size; i++)
{
    h_hx_[i] = (float)rand() / RAND_MAX;
    h_cx_[i] = (float)rand() / RAND_MAX;
}
cudaMemcpy(d_hx_, h_hx_, bunch_hidden_size * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(d_cx_, h_cx_, bunch_hidden_size * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

checkCUDNN(cudnnRNNForwardInference(cu_dnnHandle,
    cu_rnnDesc,
    seq_len,
    tensorDescs.data(),
    d_input,
    hx_desc_,
    d_hx_,
    cx_desc_,
    d_cx_,
    w_desc_,
    param_space_,
    resultDescs.data(),
    d_output,
    hy_desc_,
    d_hy_,
    cy_desc_,
    d_cy_,
    work_space_,
    workspace_size
    ));
```

when the application call cudnnRNNForwardInference api, report CUDNN_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED, I don't know which part is wrong in the code, any suggestions for these codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the reason,

```
h_input = new float[batchnum * 64];
for (int i = 0; i < batchnum * 64; i++)
{
    h_input[i] = (float)rand() / RAND_MAX;
}
cudaMalloc(&d_input, batchnum * 64 * sizeof(float));

cudaMemcpy(d_input, h_input, batchnum * 64 * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

cudaMalloc(&d_output, batchnum * 64 * sizeof(float));
```

need to allocate **seq_len * batchnum * 64** data.